# How can I change the color of xterm titlebar?

Tags: bash, colors, xterm

I want to automatically change the color of my xterm titlebar.
I would like to put code into my .bashrc so that the color changes
automatically (say depending on the directory I am in).

I know how to change the prompt and also how to change the text displayed
in the titlebar. My question is about the color of the titlebar. Right
now the color is orangish. I am using Ubuntu.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

xterm will inherit the window decoration settings of your window manager. I don't think there is currently a way of automatically changing it based on your current directory.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuEyeCandy